# Are there some tool to convert wbxml to xml in Mac OS (or in >=XCode 4.5)

Tags: xml, macos, wbxml

Are the some tool to convert from wbxml to xml in MacOS, or some simple project to provide that conversation for the >=XCode 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but you could install the [wbxml gem](http://wbxml.rubyforge.org) or [XML::WBXML](http://search.cpan.org/~glasser/XML-WBXML-0.03/lib/XML/WBXML.pm) and convert the files with one of those.